# Joining two tables so I can use ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL but hit a wall last night when I was experimenting on my website. I've been trying to figure it out now for hours with no luck, so here's my first post on Stack Overflow!

My issue is that I'm trying to sort a table of results, however what I need to sort by is from a different query from the main data. So I have a table of data that outputs fine, but I can't use ORDER BY to the field I want because it comes from a different query.

I have two tables:

```
character_
quest_globals
```

Data I need from the two tables:

```
character_.id
character_.name
character_.class
character_.level

quest_globals.charid   (Same value as character_.id)
quest_globals.name
quest_globals.value

Ordered by: quest_globals.value
```

I would like to join these two tables so I can order the results how I like. Do I need to use UNION or JOIN for this?

`character_` and `quest_globals` have a common field as `character_.id` is the same as `quest_globals.charid` so I'm guessing I use this to join?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.class, c.level, q.name, q.value 
FROM character_ c
LEFT JOIN
  quest_globals q
ON 
  q.charid  = c.id 
ORDER BY q.value
```

Also, you can give names to your columns like:

```
c.name as char_name, q.name as quest_name
```

so, it won't be so messy

Comment: Thank you, great code. I'm just tweaking a last little bit, as I left out some information in main post which I forgot whilst posting. I'm trying to add WHERE q.name = 'EXP_c.name' before the ORDER, might have to do this bit through PHP though

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT character_.id,character_.name,character_.class,character_.level,quest_globals.name,quest_globals.value
FROM character_
LEFT JOIN quest_globals ON quest_globals.charid  = character_.id 
ORDER BY quest_globals.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Query will be like this:

```
SELECT character_.id
character_.name
character_.class
character_.level
FROM character_
INNER JOIN quest_globals
ON character_.id=quest_globals.charid
ORDER BY quest_globals.value
```

hope it solves the column.